# Eliminar filas con más de un determinado número de variables cuyo valor sea NA

Tags: r

Imaginad un dataframe con 4 varibles, me gustaría eliminar los registros que contengan 2 o más variables cuyo valor sea NA

```
   mi_df <- data.frame(
  "id" = c(1, 2, 3, 4) 
  "producto" = c("a", NA, "c", NA), 
  "precio" = c(1.2, NA, 4.3, 5.6),
  "tipo" = c(NA, NA, "c", NA))
)

mi_df
```

En este caso los registros con id 2 y 4, tiene dos o más variables con NA por lo que tendrían que ser eliminados

Comment: Bienvenido Eduardo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer:

```
mi_df[rowSums(is.na(mi_df)) < 2, ]
```

`rowSums(is.na(mi_df))` suma por fila las "celdas" que son `NA`, luego solo resta filtrar las que tienen 2 o más valores